# Test form errors

Tags: testing, symfony

Do you now if we can test form errors in sf2 ?
like sf1.x:

```
  with('form')->begin()->
    hasErrors(3)->
    isError('description', 'required')->
    isError('how_to_apply', 'required')->
    isError('email', 'invalid')->
  end()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of something like this in SF2 (for the moment),

You could write your own bundle.

Or use the way symfony2 do it : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#forms.